# I have Integrate deep linking in my app but its not work

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have integrate deep linking in android app .I get result like below image and already app install in my phone but When i click on  link from message Application after app icon not show in launcher list. I don't know what is wrong in my code implementation .Thanks in advance.

[image]

Here is my menifests file code

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />


            <!-- handle website links -->
            <data
                android:host="www.abc.in"
                android:pathPattern="/event"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <data
                android:host="abc.in"
                android:pathPattern="/event"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Here is my activity code

```
  private void handleIntent() {
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to handle app links.
    Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
    String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
    Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();

    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(appLinkAction) && appLinkData != null){
        String recipeId = appLinkData.getLastPathSegment();
        Log.e(TAG,"recipeId ="+ recipeId);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your app registered https but link is http

Comment: the link in the posted image is `http` and not `https`

Answer (score 1):

The host you clicked does not match to your deeplink.
If you clicked: `https://abc.in/event`. it will work.

If you want to support deeplink from like the sample above, you should this on your current `intent-filter`

```
            <data
                android:host="maps.google.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/maps"
                android:scheme="http" />
```

**Edit:**

To support this link: https://abc.in/event/-chakravyuh-featuring-nitish-bharadwaj/1073. You need to add the following.

```
            <data
                android:host="abc.in"
                android:pathPrefix="/event"
                android:scheme="https" />
```

Comment: my click url:  https://abc.in/event/-chakravyuh-featuring-nitish-bhardwaj/1009
or other click url is : https://www.abc.in/event/-chakravyuh-featuring-nitish-bhardwaj/1009 

what is problem in my url and host
my scheme is https

Comment: @Priyankapatel is the scheme `http` or `https`?

Comment: ok ...Thank you
I  have just change  pathPattern to pathPrefix and now working fine

Comment: @Priyankapatel Good to hear. Accepting the answer would be appreciated.